# How to enforce instantiating an object in another object (that depends on it) in C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I've got this situation in my hands:

1. Object A depends on one or more of object B (and its descendants).
2. There can be multiple instances of object A and B. Which should be inserted into a list somewhere (with the list of B objects in the form of a vector inside object A that owns them).
3. Object B (and its descendants) cannot live inside another object and a unique object specifically for object A.
4. Thus, object B cannot be instantiated outside of object A.
5. If object A has been instantiated, it can create an instance of object B (and its descendants) on the fly and will push it into a vector of object B's.
6. Both object A and object B can be derived infinitely into lots of variants.

So far, I've came out with 2 solutions, and I don't think that they are all faulty.

**Solution #1:**

> Use a manager + factory class which would create and pair both object A and
>   B. Which also will manage the list / vector of object A.

The problem with this one is:
1. I need to either pass around the instance of the manager + factory object a lot to any object that needs to instantiate object A and B.
2. Because I can't make sure how many variants of object A and B there are that will be derived in the future, I couldn't do a switch/case instantiating. Or if we go the factory pattern way, I must enforce that each child of object A and B should have a pair factory class for themselves. Kind of tedious, and will possibly bloat the application if you ask me.
3. It can't enforce the 3rd and 4th points of the rules above. Except if I hide the constructors and make them private / protected, and make the manager + factory class as a friend class.

**Solution #2:**

> Make object A manage itself and will store its reference into a member static
>   vector upon creation. Object B must only be created via a method
>   called "AddB()" which will have a template class as an input,
>   and inside the method, it will instantiate the template class and store it into a vector
>   of object B.

The problem with this one is:
1. I can't really make sure that the template class that was inputted is actually a child / derivation of object B, since it is a template after all.
2. Quite possibly will add some hit on the performance because it is a template after all. FYI, I probably need instantiate it quite often, even around 2000-ish at once.
3. It still can't enforce the 3rd and 4th points of the rules above. Except if I hide the constructors and make them private / protected, and make the A class as a friend class of B class.

So, any idea about how to solve this the best way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is class 'B visible to clients of A, or just to A?

Comment: B is also visible to clients of A. There should be a getter method for each variables of B and a setter only if needed. Oh and also I forgot to mention, object A controls the lifetime of B. So B will be deleted if A that owns it was deleted. To illustrate it better, consider A as a concrete object and B as the trait / component of A.

Comment: Who is extending A and B? Is it you, or does it need to be extensible by other users of your code?

Comment: Yes, it would be me and other programmers that need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it looks like "Thus, object B cannot be instantiated outside of object A." is the crux of the issue.

The template route is probably the best, since it generates a compile-time error if the class is not a subclass of the vector type. I also made every B (Animal) class a friend of A, so A could use the private constructor. It eats away at encapsulation, and may be hard to maintain, but it works.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Farm;
class Animal {
    protected:
    Animal() {}
    public:
    virtual ~Animal() {}
    void makeSound() { cout << this->sound() << endl; }
    virtual string sound () const = 0;
    friend class Farm;
};

class Cat : Animal {
    protected:
    Cat() {}
    public:
    virtual ~Cat() {}
    virtual string sound () const { return "meow"; }
    friend class Farm;
};


class Dog : Animal {
    protected:
    Dog() {}
    public:
    virtual ~Dog() {}
    virtual string sound () const { return "bark"; }
    friend class Farm;
};

class Tractor {
    protected:
    Tractor() {}
    virtual ~Tractor() {}
    virtual string sound () const { return "rummm!"; }
    friend class Farm;
};


class Farm {
    vector< Animal * > animals;

public:
    template< typename AnimalType >
    void create() {
        animals.push_back( new AnimalType );
    }

    void disturbAnimals() {
        for( auto animal : animals ) {
            animal->makeSound();
        }
    }
};


int main( int argc_, char ** argv_ ) {
    Farm farm;
    farm.create<Cat>();
    farm.create<Dog>();

    // Generates compile-time error
    //farm.create<Tractor>();
    farm.disturbAnimals();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You're right, one of the most important thing is to enforce the instantiation to be inside object A only.  And I also thought that the template way is the better solution. But is it possible to do without using a template? I still have some reservation about using templates.

Comment: @Bawenang Rukmoko Pardian Putra, templates generate specialized code for every type that is used in the template at compile time. However, templates themselves are extremely fast because of this. There's even a whole field of C++ devoted to template programming.

Comment: IC. I didn't use templates that often, if at all. So I wouldn't know. Thanks.